# meaning of "phantasmagorical"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What are the best synonyms for ***"phantasmagorical"*** in the following context? Does it somehow imply imaginative, unstable, ever-changing, or anything else?

> Context:
>
> Thus, it was felt – in a view which reveals clear synergies with
>   Walter Benjamin’s earlier thinking on the ***phantasmagorical***
>   nature of modernity – that the ‘city that evidences dereliction and
>   decay alongside glamour and wealth is a city that can capture the
>   false historicism of modernity’. For Benjamin the ‘promises of
>   continual progress and endless improvement [were] among the
>   mystifications of capitalism’, with the ‘endless stream of identical
>   artefacts and the cyclical character of fashion’ producing what might
>   be called a ***phantasmagorical*** ‘eternal return of the same’

Comment: I'm not sure *imaginative* is really one of the "synonyms" of *phantasmagorical* (*imaginary* is better). But as to which specific aspects of the three (similar, overlapping) definitions [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phantasmagorical) the writer wants you to understand, I think that's really a matter of opinion (read: Lit Crit).

Comment: Please identify the source so that I don't have to keep looking it up. This is from Nicolas Whybrow's *Art and the City*.  As @FumbleFingers notes this is LitCrit, writing in which words have meanings private to the authors.  *Phantasmagorical* doesn't have any discernible meaning at all here, in the sense that you could substitute any adjective -- categorical, pedagogical, problematical -- and have a sentence just as sensible as the original.  The language  is  meant to obfuscate, not illuminate.  It doesn't imply anything in particular because in general you may infer anything from it.

Comment: @deadrat: I'm not sure anything of value would be lost if both instances of the word were simply removed. I'm a little surprised to find it's the 83721st (out of 86800) [least common word](http://www.wordcount.org/main.php) in the British National Corpus. The next three entries being *wangchuk, goria, stirlings, folosade* (none of which I've ever heard of). But even if it *weren't* that rare, I think it would be at least "stylistically suspect" to use it twice in one paragraph.

Comment: Did you even look??  http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/phantasmagorical

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, well played!  You're absolutely right:  leaving out the word entirely leaves a text of equivalent (lack of) meaning.  The only change would be to use *an* in "an 'eternal return of the same'".  This may be the defining characteristic of LitCrit.  Time for a favorite joke:  What do you get when you cross a LitCritic with a mafioso?  You get someone who makes you an offer you can't understand.

Comment: @HotLicks A thesaurus is of absolutely no use in trying to decipher the meaning of the word in this context.  At the very least, one would have to be familiar with the work of Walter Benjamin, and from a few minutes spent in the google, I'd guess Benjamin's work is no more accessible than Whybrow's.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, insofar as it is not a request for a simple dictionary definition, it is a request for help in deciphering literary criticism.

Comment: Kindly see the original use of the word:http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-pha2.htm

Comment: Too bad, because I have now done research on this: Benjamim wrote a book called Paris, Capital of the 19th Century (my translation, just republished). In it, he uses the word. I would be glad to translate the relevant passage if the question is reopened:http://www.nonfiction.fr/article-7668-actualite_de_walter_benjamin.htm

Answer (score 2):

Phantasmagoria is the noun form and important word literarily speaking. It conjures up worlds of Gothic horror and so forth, and the works of writers like Edgard Allan Poe (The Pit and the Pendulum) and Mervyn Peake (Gormanghast) are full of it. Indeed, with the idea of spooky, specterish, scary places their works would not even exist. Think of a poem like The Raven: Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary [in my dark attic room lit by a candle]. And Lewis Carroll even has a poem by the name. Take a look at this crowd: http://barefootplayhouse.com/shows-tickets/ Their looks make one think of the naughty, wicked things associated with the word. Oh, I forgot to mention: The Fall of the House of Usher by Poe and a lot of Steven King. Where would he be without it? Phantamagoria: an awful mixture of phantasy and illusion and changing landscapes....modernity has these qualities if one looks at it pessismistically.

Comment: Certainly *phantasmagoria* has an ordinary meaning of the dreamlike or hallucinatory.  Although I don't entirely agree with the aptness of several of your exemplars, I'm sure we could come to some agreement about applying the word to the works of Poe, Peake, King, and The Barefoot Playhouse.  Your task, however, is to explicate the meaning with regard to *Art and the City*, where your guidepost isn't Poe but Benjamin.  It's not at all clear that the word has the connotation you cite.  Or any necessary connotation at all, as FF points out.

Comment: The historical timeline from the time Baudelaire coined the term has mostly been filled with horrors that can be classified as phantasmagoria. While Victorians were sipping tea in their parlors Dickens was describing the  horrors of the poor in London and the British Empire was running amuk in India...there are so many examples....modern European history is filled with it. As is literature. Franz Kafka.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting my point across.  The meaning is clear In the context of fantasy literature (which may or may not have anything to do with the real-world horrors of Victorian poverty or depredations of the Raj).  But that's not the situation under discussion in *Art and the City*, which concerns "synergies" with another postmodernist poseur, Walter Benjamin.  We're neither in the city of Jahnsi nor the slums of London here.

Comment: It refers to Benjamin's book in French called: Paris, Capital of the 19th c.  In this way, he joins certain analyses developed by Marx in the 1844 Manuscripts and then Capital, regarding the « fetichism of commodities » and «phantasmagoria » that capital produces by diisconnecting use value from exchange value, two notions much used by Benjamin in this short book. [my translation from http://www.nonfiction.fr/article-7668-actualite_de_walter_benjamin.htm] Hmm..hedge funds? :)

Comment: Thanks for making my point for me.  *Fetishism* has an anthropological meaning in the study of religious practice and a psychological meaning in the sense of paraphilia.  There is no reason to believe that either sense has anything but the most tangential, abstract, and metaphorical meaning in Marx's abstract and metaphorical parallel between "human" relationships between people and "economic" "relationships" between capital and commodities.  There is no reason to believe that there is any concrete, meaningful distinction between "use" value and "exchange" value.

Comment: How could we demonstrate, say, that an "exchange" is or is not an ordinary kind of "use"?  So either we have new specialized technical terms or undefined abstractions of previously-defined technical terms.  In either case, it's impossible to determine by asking for dictionary definitions.  What's the emoticon for on "hedge funds"?  Are you serious or not about the aptness of the example of hedge funds?  Is "oatmeal" any more or less an apt example?

Comment: I think it is useful to read the actual text by Walter Benjamin, which is translated into English: http://www.no-w-here.org.uk/paris%20capital.pdf The terms use value and exchange value are terms used by Marx. I am not disputing them or explicating them. Though I daresay the meaning is obvious to most people.  The only way to see exactly what Benjamin meant is to read his essay and not have a disputation with me. Don't shoot the messenger. The point is that I did "locate" the term and that should have use value for the OP.

Comment: The terms *value* and *exchange* are terms used by many people.  But the term mentioned by the OP is "phantasmagorical."  It is not my thesis that *value* and *exchange* have any relationship to the OP's request.  It's yours, so I'm going to decline the chore of reading your translation of Benjamin's words.  If you can "explicate" them in a way that answers the  OP's question, please do.

Comment: It is not a claim, deadrat. It is a fact. Walter Benjamin uses the term: "The world exhibitions glorified the exchange-value of commodities. They created a framework in which their use-value receded into the background. They opened up a phantasmagoria into which people entered in order to be distracted." He uses the term at least 8 times: http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/fantasmagorie: art de faire voir des fantômes par illusion d'optique , the art of making ghosts appear through optical illusions; Also:artistic (fine arts) representation using allegories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35097/discussion-between-deadrat-and-lambie).

Answer (score 0):

"Science doesn't think", Heidegger said.
Here "phantasmagorical" looks like a kind of thought expériment which could  be qualified of **surrealistic**.

```
surrealistic - characterized by fantastic imagery and incongruous juxtapositions;
```

"a great concourse of phantasmagoric shadows"--J.C.Powys;
 "the incongruous imagery in surreal art and literature"
phantasmagoric, phantasmagorical, surreal

Comment: I renew my plea not to confuse the OP by guessing what LitCrit language means.  Presumably you mean that the *use* of "phantasmagorical" looks like a kind of thought experiment.  What does it mean for something to "look like" a thought experiment?  And what "kind" of thought experiments are there?  Do you mean a *gedankenexperiment* or do you mean just musing?  By the way, I looked up Heidegger's quote, and it makes as little sense in German as it does in English.

Comment: "Thought experiment" was concerning the Benjamin's thought and his conception of  modernity. It was audacious, I'm confused.
"Thought experiment" not in the way of Einstein for instance nor as a musing
but as estimation of a possible reality. 

Fantasmagorical is too subjective to be rationally explained,  that's why I prefer fantastic.

 “The fantastic is always a break in the acknowledged order, an irruption of the inadmissible within the changeless everyday legality”
― Roger Caillois, Au Coeur Du Fantastique